# WCF service is not accessible outside of local computer

Tags: wcf, deployment

I deployed WCF service (.NET 3.5) to IIS 5.1 (WinXP) and it's accessible from local computer. But, it's not accessible outside of local computer.

Here's my web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
      <add prefix="http://222.22.22.222:8072/"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Parus.ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://111.1.11.111:8072/AsurReceiveData/Service.svc"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <MyInspector />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Parus.ServiceBehavior" name="Parus.Service">
      <endpoint address="http://222.22.22.222:8072/AsurReceiveData/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Parus.IService">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="MyInspector" type="Parus.MessageInspectorExtension, Parus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The computer's local IP address is: 111.1.11.111:8072.
The computer's public IP address is: 222.22.22.222:8072.

What I did? I've added new TCP port in IIS 5.1 (Default Web Site Properties -> Web Site tab -> click Advanced button -> click Add button and add new port: 8072).

The project URL looks as following:

```
http://111.1.11.111:8072/ServiceFolder
```

The service looks as follows:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public const string ReplyAction = "http://222.22.22.222:8072/AsurReceiveData/Message_ReplyAction";
    public const string RequestAction = "http://222.22.22.222:8072/AsurReceiveData/Message_RequestAction";

    public Message SetData(Message requestXml)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"Path\Body.xml"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(requestXml.ToString());
        }
        Message response = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, ReplyAction, requestXml.ToString());

        return response;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I use local and public IP addresses properly. Maybe it's something else...

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why nobody is answering questions?

Comment: You haven't specified what error you're getting, but the first thing I would check is that port 8072 is allowed through the firewall.

Comment: The error is: HTTP 404, The resource cannot be found.

Comment: What are you using as your client?  The metadata is only exposed on your internal address, so you will need to be using a wcf client, you will not be able to do an HTTP GET on the WSDL for example.

Comment: Why I can't? I can use for example some another external service to get its functionality. Why I can't set up my service to be used in the same way?

Comment: You are using basicHttpBinding which requires a WCF or SOAP client, if you want to respond to HTTP GET then try WebHttpBinding - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20930/discussion-between-david-martin-and-tesicg)

Comment: No. I use some another external service that uses basicHttpBinding and I can see information from wsdl file in browser.

Comment: We use the external service of our business partner. There's one method we call. That method accepts some arguments and one of them is URL of our service. It looks as following: string content = extClient.Method1(Url, email, packSize, catalogId, requestId); Url is our service address like this: 'http://public_ip:8072/ServiceFolder/Service.svc'. As you can see their code (which is black box for us) should call our service, but they don't for some reason. All they need is URL of our service. That's the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have a firewall on you computer which blocks all incoming calls. You should turn off the firewall or open the 8072 port to be able to communicatie from other computers with you wcf service.

Comment: The new port 8072 is added to firewalls' "Exceptions" section and checked. I can access some ordinary page in the application that is deployed to IIS, for example some .html page. But, I can't access WCF service.